# How to allocate class using HeapCreate/HeapAlloc?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

How can I allocate class using HeapCreate and HeapAlloc in Delphi? The following example will just crash.

```
program Project2;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Winapi.Windows;

var
  SL: TStringList;
  Handle: THandle;
  P: ^TStringList;
begin
  Handle := HeapCreate(0, SizeOf(TStringList), SizeOf(TStringList));
  P := HeapAlloc(Handle, 0, SizeOf(TStringList));
  P.Add('some random string'); // crash

  HeapFree(Handle, 0, @P);
end.
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? `SL` is already a pointer to an instance of `TStringList`, so `P` is a *pointer to a pointer to an instance of a TStringList*.

Comment: @KenWhite I am trying to use TStringList?

Comment: This seems fraught with peril.  It sounds like what you really want is a different memory manager for Delphi.  What you're trying to do won't work.  Consider that even if you manage to create the `TStringList` on your new heap, the strings within it will still live on the shared heap, so any contention you're trying to avoid will fail just the same (assuming that's what you're trying to do).

Comment: You use `TStringList` by writing `SL := TStringList.Create;`. You don't need `HeapCreate` or `HeapAlloc`. Delphi automatically puts them on your application's heap. Seems like what you need is a Delphi tutorial.

Comment: @KenWhite No, I think he's trying to deliberately create a second heap to use in a multithreaded context - to avoid MM contention.  This is completely not the way to do it, of course, but I don't think OP's confusion is about how to create an object in the standard way.

Comment: Allocating string list instances is never a bottleneck. The payload might be.

Comment: @J...: Yeah, I got that. My point with my last comment was in response to what he replied when I asked for clarification: *I am trying to use TStringList?*. That response provided no additional information.

Answer (score 10):

Delphi provides only limited facility for allocating objects from anywhere other than the main memory manager. To do so, you need to override the class's [`NewInstance`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.NewInstance) method. That's the method the constructor calls to allocate a new instance of the class. The destruction counterpart is [`FreeInstance`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.FreeInstance).

Override those methods and call `HeapAlloc` and `HeapFree`. The number of bytes to allocate is not given by `SizeOf`, though. `SizeOf` tells you the size of the *object reference*, which is always `SizeOf(Pointer)`. You need the size of the *instance*, which is given by the class's [`InstanceSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.InstanceSize) method.

Although you can override the methods to use your chosen memory-allocation strategy, you're probably not going to be satisfied with the results because there are a few problems:

1. The `NewInstance` method doesn't accept any parameters, so there's no way for you to tell the class *which* heap to allocate from. You could have a single global heap, or a heap per class, but you can't choose which heap to use for each instance individually.
2. The `NewInstance` method is shared by all instances of a given class, so there's no way to allocate only *some* instances on your special heap and allocate the rest from the default memory manager. This is mainly another way of wording the previous problem.
3. You can't retrofit this into existing classes, so you can allocate `TMyStringList`, but not `TStringList`. (Well, you *can*, but it requires patching each class's VMT, which is generally never recommended.)

---

There are a few problems with the code you tried. First is that you never actually allocated a `TStringList`. You allocated a *pointer* to one, which, as I mentioned above, is `SizeOf(Pointer)` bytes. That's not enough memory to hold a `TStringList` instance.

You never really needed a `^TStringList` at all. You could have assigned your allocated memory directly to the `TStringList` variable `SL`:

```
SL := HealAlloc(Handle, 0, TStringList.InstanceSize);
```

Notice how I've adjusted the size.

That's still not enough, though, because while this has *allocated* some memory, it hasn't *constructed* the object. You'd need to call the constructor.

```
SL.Create;
```

Note that the constructor will allocate more memory to hold the list of strings, and allocate still more memory to hold the string contents. Those memory allocations won't go on the heap. They'll go to the default memory manager, just as they always do.

Destroying the object will be another issue. You need to call the destructor to free the string of strings, but if you do that, the destructor will attempt to free the object's memory, too. It will use the default memory manager to free it, but since you didn't use the default memory manager to allocate the `TStringList` object, the memory manager will throw an `EInvalidPointer` exception.

Delphi provides no way to destroy an object without also releasing the associated memory. That is, you cannot call `Destroy` without also calling `FreeInstance`, but `TStringList.FreeInstance` will call `FreeMem`, not `HeapFree`.

---

I recommend taking a step back from your current task and re-examining the problem you were aiming to solve with your idea of a separate heap for certain objects. There might be better solutions that don't involve as much effort to fight against what your tools are designed to do.

Comment: So I need a custom TStringList and a custom string? I need a per thread heap. So this is essential.

Comment: If you need a per-thread heap, then use a threaded memory manager. You don't need your application code to specify which heap to use for every allocation. You just need the memory manager to use a different heap for each thread. This is what I was talking about when I suggested you take a step back. You asked an *XY question*.